# Macro to detect clicking on a cell in a specific row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to get a macro to run if I click on any cell in a specific row in Excel.

Let's say I want to show a message "hello world" if I click on any cell in row 4. I tried looking around, but only got as far as the follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("4")) Then
            MsgBox "Hello World"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Obviously this is wrong, but any help in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 4 Then
            MsgBox "Hello World"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Damn. That simple... Thanks for the assist Pawel. Code works great!